# json Deserialization changes date

Tags: c#, json

Hey I'm getting diffrent date after deserialization. 
before the date is 30.03.2017, and after the date is 29.03.2017.

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeMIk.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBsYR.png)

Json string (stam value):

```
[{"a_id":1,"auctionname":"computer","deadLine":"\/Date(1490821200000)\/"},{"a_id":2,"auctionname":"keyboard","deadLine":"\/Date(1490821200000)\/"},{"a_id":3,"auctionname":"mouse","deadLine":"\/Date(1490821200000)\/"}]
```

my code:

```
[Test]
    public void GetAuctionsByJson_works()
    {
        Mock<IAuctionRespository> mockAuction = new Mock<IAuctionRespository>();
        mockAuction.Setup(m => m.Auctions).Returns(new Auction[]
            {
                new Auction { a_id=1, auctionname="computer", deadLine=DateTime.Today},
                new Auction { a_id=2, auctionname="keyboard", deadLine=DateTime.Today},
                new Auction { a_id=3, auctionname="mouse", deadLine=DateTime.Today}
            }.AsQueryable());
        CustomerController controller = new CustomerController(mockAuction.Object);
        var actual = controller.GetAuctionsByJson() as JsonResult;
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string stam = serializer.Serialize(actual.Data);
        List<Auction> result = serializer.Deserialize<List<Auction>>(serializer.Serialize(actual.Data));

        //List<Auction> result = ser.ReadObject(actual);// as List<Auction>; //null --> decirialized
    }
```

Comment: Timezone issue :)

Comment: Are you sure? What is the browser's and server's timezone? Midnight 30/3 on the browser may be 9pm 29/3 on the server if there is a 3 hour difference. The de-facto date standard is ISO8601. *With* the timezone. Your string though, contains the abandoned Ajax format that was used briefly in the 2000s. In this case, the problem is that you *can't* specify a timezone offset so the server parses this date string using the local timezone

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer isn't used. That's also a remnant of earlier days. ASP.NET Web API itself uses Json.NET

Comment: `DateTime.Today` is returns a local DateTime, ie its `.Kind` property is Local. Use `DateTime.UtcNow.Date` to get a DateTime whose Kind is `Utc`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, i think it's because i didn't specify the hour, so it used mid-night and it messed the dates.

Comment: I changed the code to  deadLine=DateTime.Today.Date and it worked

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the hours. `DateTime.Today.Date` is identical to `DateTime.Today` and `DateTime.Now.Date`. The problem is that all these calls return local time instead of UTC

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok, i've changed my code so it will use UtcNow instade of Today or Now. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues.

First, the format `\/Date(1490821200000)\/` isn't used anymore. It was used in the early 2000s when there was no defacto standard to represen time in AJAX calls. The number is an escaped number of ticks in UTC. The defacto standard is ISO8601, `2017-03-30T00:00:00Z`.

Second JavascriptSerializer isn't used anymore. It's been replaced by Json.NET even in ASP.NET Web API. I'm not sure if it understands ISO8601 or not. It isn't used anyway, except in legacy code.

Finally, `DateTime.Today` returns the *local* time. `DateTime.Today` in a +3 timezone is `30/3/2017 12:00:00 am` but `29/3/2017 09:00:00 pm`in UTC. Its `.Kind` property is `Local`. Even Json.NET would serialize this as `2017-03-30T00:00:00+03:00`

To get the current date in UTC, one should use `DateTime.UtcNow.Date`. This has a `Kind` value of `Utc`. Json.NET will serialize this as `2017-03-30T00:00:00Z`

Try changind all calls to

```
DateTime.Today
```

with

```
DateTime.UtcNow.Date
```